# REST query cannot be viewed in Internet Explorer

Tags: rest, explorer

I am trying to get the results from a site using REST call like this: `http://server1/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('list title')`

But it's giving me that Internet Explorer Cannot Display This Feed, I tried with Chrome it works, but the xml is just not formatted and not readable as it would be in explorer with collapse and expand functionalities.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: http://www.spdoctor.net/Pages/message.aspx?name=internet-explorer-cannot-display-this-feed

should change the settings to display what you want

(edit) scratch that thought, I just re-read your post, and I dont think this is what you asked

Answer (score 13):

To open REST API Query url `http://server1/sites/mysite/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('list title')`
in browser like internet explorer
Goto **Internet Options** -> **Content**->**Feeds and Web Slices**->**Settings**->   **uncheck** "**Turn on feed reading view**". It will show the results of REST API Query as like in browsers like Google chrome

Comment: This is the answer. #Concise This answer is preferred over Brent's because the answer is here and not @ a link.  We can provide the answer and provide a link for credit or reference but the actual answer should be here in stack.